# How to use NSpredicate with transformable attribute in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate, transformable

In my core data entity i have a transformable attribute called "dateArray" it as  NSdate array.

When i fetch data i want to check like this

```
     let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateArray contains[cd] %@ ",givendate))
```

That is i want to check a "givenDate" is in the transformable attribute of core data.

But after researching i found that cannot able to perform predicate directly to a transformable attribute.If anybody helps with another solution means it will be useful

Thanks

Comment: The only solutions are 1) Fetch all objects and filter the arrays in memory – 2) Replace the transformable property by a to-many relationship.

Comment: But the question did not have a good solution

Comment: There is – to the best of my knowledge – no better solution. But it is the same question. If anyone finds a better answer then it can be added to the referenced Q&A.